# Recursive method with exception, logical error

Tags: java

I am trying to make a code which inserts a user input until the input is correct (double), it will loop again until the input is correct.

Below is the code:

```
private static double variableNumberInput(String variableName, Scanner userInput) {
    double userInputNumber = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println(String.format("Input value: %s", variableName));
        userInputNumber = Double.valueOf(userInput.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("Please try again");
        variableNumberInput(variableName, userInput);
    }
    return userInputNumber;
}
```

It worked perfectly as I wanted... , until I test it and purposely insert a wrong input first (using a string), after that inserted the correct input. The result it returns 0.

```
"Input value: X"
incorrect input
"Please try again"
"Input value: X"
1
returns -> 0
```

I did try to debug it, and it apparently returns the correct value, but somehow after the input is correct it then calls the method again *inside the catch block* only to return 0.

Can't figure out why it behave that way, can someone please help me understand?

Comment: Fix: Change the line to `userInputNumber  = variableNumberInput(variableName, userInput);`.

Comment: Or just `return variableNumberInput(variableName, userInput);`

Comment: Thank you JohannesKuhn and Abra for the help, it solved the return value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving the result of your recursive calls. Try this:

```java
private static double variableNumberInput(String variableName, Scanner userInput) {
    double userInputNumber = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println(String.format("Input value: %s", variableName));
        userInputNumber = Double.valueOf(userInput.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        System.out.println("Please try again");
        userInputNumber = variableNumberInput(variableName, userInput);
    }
    return userInputNumber;
}
```

Notice the change in the `catch` block.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it now.. Since it always will return 0 because its on the previous catch block..

thank you for the effort of rewriting the code and giving a clear example :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect something else? You probably print result from the very first method call and since it's 0, that's what it'll return.

Instead you should return whatever result the recursive call returned.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that when I do it in the catch block, it always eventually will return to it again.. Thank you for helping me understand Mr. Pluta